# mysqli_fetch_array Gives Me Duplicate Rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have this SQL command :

```
SELECT Username FROM Family WHERE Parent = '$Username' LIMIT 10
```

When I run that command on my PHPMyAdmin and put some $Username on it, I have this in result :

```
+----------+
| Username |
+----------+
| johndoe  |
+----------+
```

but when I try to create function like this :

```
function userParent($Username)
{
global $con;
$Result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Username FROM Family WHERE Parent = '$Username' LIMIT 10");
$Result = mysqli_fetch_array($Result);
return $Result; 
}
```

I have this array in return :

```
Array ( [0] => johndoe [Username] => johndoe )
```

So when I 'call' that function on my script using foreach loop like this :

```
$Parent = userParent('james');
foreach ($Parent as $value){
echo $value . '<br>';
}
```

I always have duplicate 'johndoe' in return. I believe this duplicate rows caused by mysqli_fetch_array. How to solve this duplicate rows from mysqli_fetch_array?

thanks

Comment: You're using `mysqli`, but completely disregarding [proper SQL escaping practices](http://bobby-tables.com/). If you use [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) you won't have any nasty SQL injection bugs like you seem to have here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array()` returns both an associative and numeric based array of your MySQL results. Use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a dupe, it's documented at http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_array. By default the function returns a dual-keyed array (numeric + string). if you want just one type, then use the specific

```
mysqli_fetch_row() [numeric only]
mysqli_fetch_assoc() [keyed only]
or
mysqli_fetch_array($result, $fetch_mode);
```

Comment: @bwoebi: He's not talking about `mysql_`.

Answer (score 0):

See for `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. This function omits the numerically indexed array part.

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php, It's returning what it is supposed to.

By default, it uses `MYSQLI_BOTH`, so the array has *both** numeric and associative keys.  Pass either `MYSQLI_ASSOC` or `MYSQLI_NUM` as the 2nd parameter to `mysqli_fetch_array` to only get one index type.

```
$Result = mysqli_fetch_array($Result, MYSQLI_NUM);
```